# PWA will soon not automatically show Add to Homescreen prompt

Tags: progressive-web-apps

Currently, Chrome show automatically the Add to Homescreen prompt event a PWA  meets the criteria.

My particule case : I wish that Chrome show the add to Homescreen only when we will need to trigger the .prompt().

Is posible this from manifest.json?

Which ways I could implement for this case?

Thanks

Comment: Share some code, what have you tried?

Comment: A2HS is not yet a web standard and it only works in Chrome. 

For starter, how chrome work is that it will fire and event call "beforeinstallprompt", and you need to listen to that event in order to do something with A2HS. If you want to modify and prevent default behaviour, you need to use `event.preventDefault()`